# How to make current wpf scale with DPI?

Tags: c#, wpf

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I enable dpiAware?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13448180/how-do-i-enable-dpiaware)

I have a WPF application with Dpi awareness disabled:

```
[assembly: System.Windows.Media.DisableDpiAwareness]
```

But when user change it to 125% or 150%, they are not able to see the lower half of the application GUI.  Removing the above line has no effect.

How can I have the GUI become smaller when user changes the DPI?

Comment: Uhh... Re-enable DPI awareness?

Comment: If I take away the [assembly: System.Windows.Media.DisableDpiAwareness], it gives me the same result.