# How do I enable dpiAware?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

How can I enable dpiAware into this existing app.manifest:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <asmv1:assembly manifestVersion="1.0" xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" xmlns:asmv1="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" xmlns:asmv2="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v2" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
      <assemblyIdentity version="1.0.0.0" name="MyApplication.app"/>
      <trustInfo xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v2">
        <security>
          <requestedPrivileges xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
            <!-- UAC Manifest Options
                If you want to change the Windows User Account Control level replace the 
                requestedExecutionLevel node with one of the following.


        <requestedExecutionLevel  level="asInvoker" uiAccess="false" />
        <requestedExecutionLevel  level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />
        <requestedExecutionLevel  level="highestAvailable" uiAccess="false" />

            Specifying requestedExecutionLevel node will disable file and registry virtualization.
            If you want to utilize File and Registry Virtualization for backward 
            compatibility then delete the requestedExecutionLevel node.
        -->
        <requestedExecutionLevel level="asInvoker" uiAccess="false" />
      </requestedPrivileges>
    </security>
  </trustInfo>

  <compatibility xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:compatibility.v1">
    <application>
      <!-- A list of all Windows versions that this application is designed to work with. Windows will automatically select the most compatible environment.-->

      <!-- If your application is designed to work with Windows 7, uncomment the following supportedOS node-->
      <!--<supportedOS Id="{35138b9a-5d96-4fbd-8e2d-a2440225f93a}"/>-->

    </application>
  </compatibility>

  <!-- Enable themes for Windows common controls and dialogs (Windows XP and later) -->
  <!-- <dependency>
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity
          type="win32"
          name="Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls"
          version="6.0.0.0"
          processorArchitecture="*"
          publicKeyToken="6595b64144ccf1df"
          language="*"
        />
    </dependentAssembly>
  </dependency>-->

</asmv1:assembly>
```

Answer (score 9):

According to [Manifest Madness](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2013/09/10/manifest-madness.aspx), if you plan to support **Windows 8.1** you should use a bit different value for this setting:

```
<asmv3:application>
  <asmv3:windowsSettings xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SMI/2005/WindowsSettings">
    <dpiAware>True/PM</dpiAware>
  </asmv3:windowsSettings>
</asmv3:application>
```

Comment: That is specifically to support per monitor DPI settings on Win 8.1 which your application may not actually support. Alexei's answer works just fine on Win 8.1 but will have a single DPI setting for all monitors.

Answer (score 6):

According to [Declaring Managed Applications As DPI-Aware](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee308410.aspx) you need to add followng section inside "assembly" element:

```
<asmv3:application  xmlns:asmv3="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3" >
    <asmv3:windowsSettings xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SMI/2005/WindowsSettings">
      <dpiAware>true</dpiAware>
    </asmv3:windowsSettings>
  </asmv3:application>
```

Comment: Alexei Levenkov, how does this work? There is no assembly element, just an asmv1:assembly? If I put it in that element, the app crashes at start with ArgumentNullException...

Comment: @andreas I'm not sure what you did. Please consider asking new question (linking to this one to show where you found info/tried) and post what you tried there. It is almost impossible to guess what type of errors one makes and very hard to post code in comments.

Comment: I will, but when looking at the OP manifest, it looks very similar to mine. He also has no "assembly" element in his code, that why I thought there was an obvious answer. ;-)

Comment: @andreas I suspect that you are talking about difference between default and non-default prefix for XML nodes (http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml-names/#defaulting) - OP's manifest indeed had "assembly" node at the root (with prefix "asmv1:" mapped to correct namespace).

Answer (score 0):

Ten years later, in Visual Studio 2022, you do not have to manually edit code in manifest files for DPI awareness at all, if you simply use this project setting:

**Manifest Tool > Input and Output > DPI Awareness > [choose an option]**