# How do I create dpi aware wpf application?

Tags: c#, wpf

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I enable dpiAware?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13448180/how-do-i-enable-dpiaware)

I have few WPF application window with `Height="768" Width="1024"`

When user change the DPI to 125%, they won't be able to view bottom half of the window?

What is the easiest way to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Does this happen only with WPF window?
Are other windows shown correctly?
When user increases DPI WPF proportionally increases the window by making pixels 'bigger'.
WPF is made to be DPI resolution independent.
If something has the width of 96px = 1 Inch it must have the same size for different resolutions. For 125% DPI res width becomes 120 device (!) pixels. If user's monitor does not support high dpi res than window probably will occupy more area than available on the screen.

Comment: This is what I thought, WPF is made to be DPI resolution independent. Maybe I have did something wrong, I don't know. Everything became big and not able to show all the properties in the Window.

Comment: There's simply no reason to change DPI if monitor does not support it ;)

Comment: User has complaint they won't be able to view the whole windows after they had change to 125% DPI.

Comment: The question is why he does so.

Comment: Maybe, because he/she can't read the 10pt text on FullHD-Laptop monitors anymore. If the application doesn't provide a method to increase the font size, they just increase the dpis in the settings. Totally valid workaround for a non-ergonomic application.