# turn off x-ms-webview autoscaling

Tags: javascript, webview, dpi, windows-10-universal

I use a full-screen `x-ms-webview` to display a webapp.

The web component is zoomed just like if on Internet Explorer I select "150%".

How can I force the webview scale to 100% programmatically?

I don't know if this is related to the **dpi-aware** mode at [How do I enable dpiAware?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13448180/how-do-i-enable-dpiaware) , in such a case I'd like to know where to insert the proposed changes to the manifest, as Visual Studio Windows 10 express seems to have a different Manifest format (package.appxmanifest)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found that webview accurately responds to `@-ms-viewport` selector, so I was able to configure the screen to fit my needs. Also found that `window.devicePixelRatio` is updated accordingly.

```
@-ms-viewport {
    width: 1920px;
    height: 1080px; 
}
```

or

```
@-ms-viewport {
    width: device-width;
    height: device-height; 
}
```