# How to make C# application (asmv1) DPI-aware by changing app.manifest?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, manifest, dpi

Referring to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13448180/how-do-i-enable-dpiaware) question, is there a way to make a C# application (asmv1) with the following manifest DPI-aware to prevent automatic scaling by the OS?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<asmv1:assembly manifestVersion="1.0" xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" xmlns:asmv1="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" xmlns:asmv2="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v2" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<assemblyIdentity version="1.0.0.0" name="MyApplication.app" />
<trustInfo xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v2">
<security>
  <requestedPrivileges xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
    <!-- UAC Manifest Options
        If you want to change the Windows User Account Control level replace the 
        requestedExecutionLevel node with one of the following.

    <requestedExecutionLevel  level="asInvoker" uiAccess="false" />
    <requestedExecutionLevel  level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />
    <requestedExecutionLevel  level="highestAvailable" uiAccess="false" />

        Specifying requestedExecutionLevel node will disable file and registry virtualization.
        If you want to utilize File and Registry Virtualization for backward 
        compatibility then delete the requestedExecutionLevel node.
    -->
    <requestedExecutionLevel level="asInvoker" uiAccess="false" />
  </requestedPrivileges>
  <applicationRequestMinimum>
    <defaultAssemblyRequest permissionSetReference="Custom" />
    <PermissionSet class="System.Security.PermissionSet" version="1" Unrestricted="true" ID="Custom" SameSite="site" />
  </applicationRequestMinimum>
</security>
</trustInfo>
```